# Chef : run jenkins agent as a background process on a node

Tags: ruby, unix, jenkins, process, chef-infra

I'm running this command manually on console, `java -jar agent.jar -jnlpUrl {{master_url}}/computer/{{slave_name}}/slave-agent.jnlp -secret {{secret_key}} > /dev/null 2>&1 &`

basically it is starting the jenkins slave in  background and it works fine, now when i try to do the same thing in Chef, the chef-client process hangs and gets timed out because process never goes in background and session remains active.

```
command = Mixlib::ShellOut.new("java -jar agent.jar -jnlpUrl {{master_url}}/computer/{{slave_name}}/slave-agent.jnlp -secret {{secret_key}}" > /dev/null 2>&1 &")

command.run_command
```

Answer (score 0):

You really should be using a proper service layer for this, which is systemd in all modern Linux distros.

Comment: Instead of using JNLP method OR creating a custom service for this i tried using SSH method to launch slaves from master. It's working fine now. Anyways, thanks for your input :)